# get the device or browser width

Tags: php, html

I want to get the browser width or device width for writing various condition based on width.I want to get the width on page load in php to write consitional statement

```
<?php
 newt_init();
 newt_get_screen_size (&$cols, &$rows);
 newt_finished();
 print "Your terminal size is: {$cols}x{$rows}\n";
?>
```

I caught error as shown below

> Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed

Comment: Isn't the error message you get crystal clear?

Comment: see this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971261/php-5-4-call-time-pass-by-reference-easy-fix-available

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101207/get-users-screenviewport-dimensions-in-php-on-first-load

Comment: Remove the `&` from the call arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the screen resolution using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php)

Comment: I don't want to get the size in javascript

Comment: The error message (and how to use references to not get it) is explained in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Comment: I have tried http://php.wudi.in/function.newt-get-screen-size.html but not working

Comment: @user3386779 The Newt library has nothing to do with browsers.